Tigergarph Select statement v2 OFFSET does not work in the limitClause
I am trying to use SQL like version of tigergraph GSQL and having something weird whenever I use OFFSET it always returns an empty result set, while if I don't use offset it works fine, any idea about that.
CREATE OR REPLACE DISTRIBUTED QUERY PostsQuery(/* Parameters here */) FOR GRAPH MyGraph{ 
    SELECT p.id, p.body, p.created_at, p.featured_at INTO data
    FROM Post:p
    LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1;
    PRINT data;
}

Outputs:
[
  {
    "data": []
  }
]

while if offset is omitted
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "body": "sdadsa.",
        "created_at": "2016-12-27 16:41:10",
        "featured_at": "1970-01-01 00:00:00",
        "id": 8
      },
      {
        "body": "sdadsa.",
        "created_at": "2016-12-28 01:22:05",
        "featured_at": "1970-01-01 00:00:00",
        "id": 9
      }
    ]
  }
]

As mentioned on their docs (EBNF for SQL-Like Select Statement) as it is mentioned limitClause is supported
EBNF for SQL-Like Select Statement
sqlSelectBlock := sqlSelectClause
               fromClause
               [whereClause]
               [groupByClause]
               [havingClause]
               [orderClause]
               [limitClause]

sqlSelectClause := SELECT [DISTINCT] columnExpr ("," columnExpr)*
               INTO tableName
columnExpr := expr [AS columnName]
            | aggregator "("[DISTINCT] expr ")" [AS columnName]
columnName := name
tableName := name

EBNF for LIMIT Clause
limitClause := LIMIT ( expr | expr "," expr | expr OFFSET expr )

Tried a lot of combinations of setting offset to 0 and I am sure that vertices getting queried is more than 20k
Any help would be appreciated! thanks
